# Why does the same code renered in React and in plain CSS provide different results:

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am experimenting with `span` and `nowrap` and I'm getting different results in vanilla JS and React.

For example, with this css:

```
span {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

using this in regular javascript:

```
<div>
    <span> lorem ipsum dolor </span>
    <span> lorem ipsum dolor </span>
    <span> lorem ipsum dolor </span>
</div>
```

vs.

```
class App extends React.Component{
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <span> lorem ipsum lorem ipsum </span>
        <span> lorem ipsum lorem ipsum </span>
        <span> lorem ipsum lorem ipsum </span>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

In React, it won't wrap the span's to the next line.  Is this a bug or is the behavior expected to be different?  How would I get the react to mimic the behavior of the css.

In React, it never wraps.  In Vanilla JS, it wraps each statement as a block, which is the desired behavior.

(edited)jsbin's for reference:

1)https://jsbin.com/zuwonirape/edit?html,css,js,output

2)https://jsbin.com/poqezobevo/1/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: you are correctly adding the CSS in react ?

Comment: you have this `div {
  display: inline-block;
}` in the react so it's a normal behavior

Comment: also in react there is a contatenation of span .. no white space between, so no wrap ... i guess React remove whitespace

Comment: make sure you are importing and using the css correctly with react.
open the dev tool and see if the span receivedthe new style.
if he does not received the new style,  the problem is the css connection to the page.

Comment: I edited the bins, removing `inline-block` has no impact.

Comment: span received the css

Comment: The intended behavior is to wrap the full span, not just a single word from the span.  So this works perfectly outside of react but doesn't when using React

Comment: read all my comments :) i added the answser in the last one ;)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, if there is contatenation of span in React, how would you reproduce this behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not CSS issue, but is caused by the way JSX handles whitespace, which is slightly different from normal html.

According to the [JSX In Depth](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#string-literals-1) React guide:

> JSX removes whitespace at the beginning and ending of a line. It also removes blank lines. **New lines adjacent to tags are removed**; new lines that occur in the middle of string literals are condensed into a single space.

So `App` gets rendered as

```
<div><span> lorem ipsum lorem ipsum </span><span> lorem ipsum lorem ipsum </span><span> lorem ipsum lorem ipsum </span></div>
```

which won't break between the spans.

To replicate the behavior of the html fragment, you can add some explicit spaces:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <span> lorem ipsum lorem ipsum </span>{' '}
      <span> lorem ipsum lorem ipsum </span>{' '}
      <span> lorem ipsum lorem ipsum </span>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: another option is something like:  `<span>text</span><span style={{ whitespace: 'nowrap' }} /><span> ........` . I found this worked but it's very ugly.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Oblosys is right, if you go back to your HTML and take out the line breaks so that you have

```
<div>
  <span> lorem ipsum lorem ipsum </span><span> lorem ipsum lorem ipsum </span><span> lorem ipsum lorem ipsum </span><span> lorem ipsum lorem ipsum </span>
</div>
```

You will see that it renders like it does in React - because this is what your JSX compiles to.

My suggestion is to apply the inline-block style to your span elements:

```
span {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

see how that looks: https://jsbin.com/ponidij/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: I realize now that I should have written this in a comment on Oblosys's answer - still getting familiar with stack overflow :)